# Sliding in Winforms form

Tags: c#, winforms, loops

I'm making a form at the bottom of the screen and I want it to slide upwards so I wrote the following code:

```
int destinationX = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width / 2) - (this.Width / 2);
int destinationY = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - this.Height;

this.Location = new Point(destinationX, destinationY + this.Height);

while (this.Location != new Point(destinationX, destinationY))
{
    this.Location = new Point(destinationX, this.Location.Y - 1);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

but the code just runs through and shows the end position without showing the form sliding in which is what I want.  I've tried Refresh, DoEvents - any thoughts?

Comment: @rs: I put "Winforms" into the title to differentiate from WPF, and removed C# because it's already in a tag, and should not also be in the title. I used the WinForms tag because that's the technology you're using. Do you object for some reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the code in a background thread. Example:

```
        int destinationX = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width / 2) - (this.Width / 2);
        int destinationY = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - this.Height;

        Point newLocation = new Point(destinationX, destinationY + this.Height);

        new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            do
            {
                 // this line needs to be executed in the UI thread, hence we use Invoke
                this.Invoke(new Action(() => { this.Location = newLocation; }));

                newLocation = new Point(destinationX, newLocation.Y - 1);
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            while (newLocation != new Point(destinationX, destinationY));
        })).Start();
```

Comment: This is nice, but I'm seeing it go too slow on an older machine even though I set Sleep value to 1. It would be better if it had a total time to complete the animation and incremented position based on amount of time that has passed.

Answer (score 7):

Try using a Timer event instead of a loop.

Comment: Kinda hacky but I'll give it a try :)

Comment: @rs - not hacky, it's the only good way. I'm surprised `DoEvents` didn't work, but really that's a good thing because `DoEvents` is seriously hacky.